# Error while installing Jupyter: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, pip, jupyter, easy-install, failed-installation

I tried installing `Jupyter` through `pip` and it failed showing this.

> The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
>   that are not within the `EasyInstall` build area, and has been
>   aborted.
>
> This package cannot be safely installed by `EasyInstall`, and may not
>   support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
>   script by hand.  Please, inform the package's author and the
>   `EasyInstall` maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is
>   available.

Comment: What is your question? And why would you think that your question would be on-topic on this site?

Answer (score 6):

Try to upgrade your packages:

`pip install --upgrade setuptools`

`pip install --upgrade pip`

its seems like missmatch in your versions

Answer (score -1):

simply follow this to install jupyter in windows :-

1nd - Go to file manager and find python folder (like:-*python*,*python37*,*python39* etc...) may be it's in (***C:\Python39***) or (***C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Programs\python39***) .

2rd - in python folder open Scripts folder (Ex:- ***C:\......\python39\Scripts***) and copy this path.

3rd - run cmd as administrator and past above path using cd (like:- cd ***C:\.....\python39\Scripts***)

4th - now simply use jupyter install command (like:- **pip install jupyterlab**)